# VLC Python - Change Video Orientation (Or Rotate) using Python Bindings

Tags: python, video, orientation, vlc, libvlc

I have some video streams I am able to get running in a VLC window and attach it to a QT widget - which is all fantastic.

Some of these video streams though are oriented differently than others, and I cannot figure out how to set the orientation - so some of my videos are displaying sideways.

Does anyone know how I can change this?

Answer (score 2):

Not all of the `vlc` options are available (exposed) using `vlc.py`.
I am not aware of a method of orienting a video at the media level. This has to be done using the `vlc.Instance`.
This pre-supposes that you know the orientation required beforehand.
There are 2 options that I am familiar with:

```
--video-filter=rotate --rotate-angle=nnn.n
```

and

```
--video-filter=transform --transform-type=type
```

where `type` is one of {90,180,270,hflip,vflip,transpose,antitranspose}

code examples would be:

```
vlc.Instance('--no-xlib --quiet --video-filter=rotate --rotate-angle=90.0')
```

and

```
vlc.Instance('--no-xlib --quiet --video-filter=transform --transform-type=vflip')
```